# Robust standard errors OLS for term structure

Tags: yield-curve, parameter-estimation

Suppose i have estimated the following model with OLS: $y_{1,t+1} - y_{1,t} = \alpha + \beta y_{1,t} + \epsilon_{t+1}$. Where $y_{1,t}$ is the 1 month zero-coupon yield at time t. What would be an appropriate way to obtain standard errors robust to heteroskedasticity and residual autocorrelation?

Comment: Newey-West estimator corrects for those. Btw. your regression is equivalent to just regressing yield on last period yield and a constant, which would be a more standard way to write this.